# The meaning of "be in touch about something"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

I heard a line in British TV series "peep show" that is

> It's a logo, for when people are in touch about doing baseball caps with my initials on.

I suppose it says 'for when people are in contact about making baseball caps'? I'm not sure. Would be great if there's anyone who could help me with it. Thanks!

Comment: ***Doing*** *baseball caps* is itself an unnatural phrase—and I'm not certain exactly what the person is trying to convey with that. It could be making them, it could be wearing them, or it could possibly be something else I can't think of immediately.

Comment: https://twitter.com/peepshowqotd/status/508708340252540928 and https://peepshow.gifglobe.com/scene/?id=fKd4WKpZsgKD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "be in touch" means to make some kind of communication, often by email or phone.

> Thank you for coming to the job interview. We will be in touch.

(We will communicate with you later to tell you if you have the job or not.)

So "to be in touch about doing baseball caps with my initials on", means "to phone or email me regarding making baseball caps with my initials".

This doesn't make much sense. However "Peep show" is a comedy, so this could be an absurd joke. It seems that Jeremy is doodling on letters addressed to Mark. He is designing a logo with his initials to put on a baseball cap, in case he ever gets an offer to make a custom baseball cap.  Mark comments on how unlikely this is by saying, ironically, "good to be prepared".

Comment: Thank you soooo much James! I fully got the point. Hope you have a wonderful day :)